# Expanding CMake variables inside a string

Tags: cmake, yaml

My goal is to provide a default YAML config file that would be written at configure time.

Do something like that:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
get_filename_component(SOUND_FILE beep.wav ABSOLUTE)
file(READ conf.template CONF_TEMPLATE)
file(WRITE conf.example.yaml "${CONF_TEMPLATE}")
...
```

`conf.template`:

```
...
path: ${SOUND_FILE}
...
```

But when I write the file, variables are not expanded, it writes `${VAR_NAME}`.

Is there a way to tell CMake to expand the variables in a string before writing to the file?

Comment: `string(REGEX REPLACE "\${SOUND_FILE}" ....`. Typically you use https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this solution would require me to add one `string()` command for each variable I want to substitute right?

Answer (score 1):

Use [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) for templating.